# Cloudinary multiple image upload in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, cloudinary

I have an image upload defined as follows in my Django app with Cloudinary package,

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = CloudinaryField('image')
```

I Would like to make this field upload mutliple images. How do I do this?

Comment: did it work for you?

Answer (score 6):

A photo holding multiple images becomes a photo album, or a photo gallery. I'd remodel al follows:

```
class PhotoAlbum(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()  # or whatever a photo album has

class Photo(models.Model):
    file = CloudinaryField('image')
    album = models.ForeignKey(PhotoAlbum, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='photos')
```

Usage example:

```
>>> album = PhotoAlbum.objects.create(name='myalbum')
>>> photo = Photo.objects.create(album=album, image=...)
```

Now, the `Photo` knows its `PhotoAlbum`:

```
>>> photo = Photo.objects.first()
>>> photo.album
<PhotoAlbum: myalbum>
```

The `PhotoAlbum` keeps track of all the `Photo`s:

```
>>> album = PhotoAlbum.objects.first()
>>> album
<PhotoAlbum: myalbum>
>>> album.photos.all()
<QuerySet [<Photo: Photo-1>]>
>>> album == Photo.objects.first().album
>>> True
>>> Photo.objects.first() == album.photos.first()
>>> True
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it like that:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    photos = models.ManyToManyField('ChildPhoto',blank=True)

class ChildPhoto(models.Model):
    photo = CloudinaryField('image')
```

You can upload many photos and the Photo model will have a manytomany to the ChildPhoto model